# Version clash of pip packages, when doing conda env export

Tags: pip, conda

I am having problems when creating a conda environment from a .yml file I created previously.
When running `conda env create -f myenv.yml` I get an error:

```
Pip subprocess error:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-tests==0.0.0 (from -r /home/robin/condaenv.m8gm40vv.requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for anaconda-tests==0.0.0 (from -r /home/robin/condaenv.m8gm40vv.requirements.txt (line 2))
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

The versions:
`pip 10.0.1`
and
`conda 4.6.14`

The .yml file looks ok, and the all pip packages are included.

Previously, I've tried upgrading to `pip 19.0.1` but then there were a lot of version clashes with other packages (because I am using python 3.5.2), so I had to downgrade it.

I assume it might be something related to the conda version I am using because the error is about `anaconda-tests==0.0.0`.

#### UPDATE:

After deleting `anaconda-tests==0.0.0` from my .yml file there were other conflicting packages, so I just deleted them or deleted the "=xxxx" part after the version number. Now I managed to create the environment successfully.

For reference the outputs from the original environment (the one I exported)

`conda list`:

```
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
anaconda-tests            0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
atari-py                  0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
azure                     1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
azure-common              1.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt                0.20.2                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-common         0.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-compute        0.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-network        0.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-nspkg          2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-resource       0.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-mgmt-storage        0.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-nspkg               2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
azure-servicebus          0.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-servicemanagement-legacy 0.20.2                   pypi_0    pypi
azure-storage             0.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
backports-weakref         1.0rc1                   pypi_0    pypi
baselines                 0.1.4                     dev_0    <develop>
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
bleach                    1.5.0                    py35_0  
boto3                     1.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
box2d                     2.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
box2d-kengz               2.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
box2d-py                  2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
cached-property           1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2017.7.27.1              pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     6.6                      py35_0    jjhelmus
cloudpickle               0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.3.9                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0  
cython                    0.27.3                   pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.10.20                       0  
decorator                 4.1.2                    py35_0  
dill                      0.2.7.1                  pypi_0    pypi
dm-control                0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.14                     pypi_0    pypi
edward                    1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py35_0  
enum34                    1.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.1.0                         0  
filelock                  2.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
flask                     0.12.2                   py35_0  
fontconfig                2.12.1                        3  
freetype                  2.5.5                         2  
future                    0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
glfw                      1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
glib                      2.50.2                        1  
gpflow                    1.1.0                     dev_0    <develop>
gpy                       1.8.5                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0  
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         0  
gym                       0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.7.0               np112py35_0  
hdf5                      1.8.17                        2  
hmmlearn                  0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
html5lib                  0.9999999                py35_0  
icu                       54.1                          0  
idna                      2.5                      pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                 pypi_0    pypi
ipdb                      0.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py35_0  
ipython                   6.1.0                    py35_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py35_0  
ipywidgets                5.1.5                    py35_0    menpo
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0  
jbig                      2.1                           0  
jedi                      0.10.2                   py35_2  
jinja2                    2.9.6                    py35_0  
jmespath                  0.9.3                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.10.3                   py35_0    menpo
jpeg                      9b                            0  
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py35_0  
jupyter-console           5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            5.1.0                    py35_0  
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py35_0  
keras                     2.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
lasagne                   0.2.dev1                 pypi_0    pypi
libffi                    3.2.1                         1  
libgcc                    5.2.0                         0  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1  
libiconv                  1.14                          0  
libpng                    1.6.27                        0  
libsodium                 1.0.10                        0  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libtiff                   4.0.6                         3  
libtorch                  0.1.12                  nomkl_0  [nomkl]
libxcb                    1.12                          1  
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0  
llvmlite                  0.19.0                   py35_0  
lxml                      4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mako                      1.0.6                    py35_0  
markdown                  2.6.11                   pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2  
matplotlib                2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.7.4                    py35_0  
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0  
mock                      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mpi4py                    2.0.0                    py35_2  
mpich2                    1.4.1p1                       0  
msgpack-python            0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
mujoco-py                 1.50.1.56                pypi_0    pypi
multipledispatch          0.4.9                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 5.2.1                    py35_0  
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py35_0  
networkx                  2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
nomkl                     1.0                           0  
nose                      1.3.7                    pypi_0    pypi
nose2                     0.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  5.0.0                    py35_0  
numba                     0.34.0              np112py35_0  
numexpr                   2.6.4                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.14.4                   pypi_0    pypi
observations              0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.44                     py35_0  
openblas                  0.2.19                        0  
opencv-python             3.4.1.15                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv3                   3.1.0                    py35_0    menpo
openssl                   1.0.2r               h7b6447c_0  
pachi-py                  0.0.21                   pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.20.3                   py35_0  
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py35_0  
paramz                    0.8.5                    pypi_0    pypi
path-py                   10.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
path.py                   10.3.1                   py35_0  
pbr                       3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.39                          1  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py35_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0  
pillow                    5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.0.3                   pypi_0    pypi
progressbar2              3.34.3                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            1.0.14                   py35_0  
protobuf                  3.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.5.2                    py35_0  
pybox2d                   2.3.1post2               py35_0    kne
pycparser                 2.18                     py35_0  
pygame                    1.9.2a0                  py35_0    kne
pyglet                    1.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.2.0                    py35_0  
pyopengl                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py35_0  
pyprind                   2.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_2  
pyro-ppl                  0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.5.2                         0  
python-dateutil           2.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python-graphviz           0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python-utils              2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   0.1.12             py35_nomkl_0  [nomkl]
pytz                      2018.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    3.12                     pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py35_0  
qt                        5.6.2                         5  
qtconsole                 4.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.18.3                   pypi_0    pypi
rllab                     0.1.0                     dev_0    <develop>
roboschool                1.0                       dev_0    <develop>
s3transfer                0.1.10                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                39.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1  
sip                       4.19.12          py35he6710b0_0  
six                       1.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
swig                      3.0.10                        0  
tensorboard               1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.6                      py35_0  
testpath                  0.3.1                    py35_0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
torch                     0.3.0.post4              pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   4.5.1                    py35_0  
tqdm                      4.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0  
urllib3                   1.22                     pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.31.1                   pypi_0    pypi
widgetsnbextension        1.2.3                    py35_1    menpo
xlrd                      1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
zeromq                    4.1.5                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3  
zmq                       0.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

`pip freeze`:

```
absl-py==0.2.2
actionlib==1.11.9
anaconda-tests==0.0.0
angles==1.9.11
astor==0.6.2
atari-py==0.1.1
azure==1.0.3
azure-common==1.1.8
azure-mgmt==0.20.2
azure-mgmt-common==0.20.0
azure-mgmt-compute==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-network==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==0.20.1
azure-mgmt-storage==0.20.0
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-servicebus==0.20.1
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.2
azure-storage==0.20.3
backports.weakref==1.0rc1
-e git+https://github.com/openai/baselines.git@a6b1bc70f156dc45c0da49be8e80941a88021700#egg=baselines
BehaviourRepresentation==0.1
bleach==1.5.0
bondpy==1.8.3
boto3==1.4.6
botocore==1.6.0
Box2D==2.3.1
Box2D-kengz==2.3.3
box2d-py==2.3.1
cached-property==1.3.0
camera-calibration==1.12.23
camera-calibration-parsers==1.11.13
catkin==0.7.8
certifi==2017.7.27.1
cffi==1.11.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.6
cloudpickle==0.4.0
colorama==0.3.9
cv-bridge==1.12.8
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.27.3
decorator==4.1.2
diagnostic-analysis==1.9.3
diagnostic-common-diagnostics==1.9.3
diagnostic-updater==1.9.3
dill==0.2.7.1
dm-control==0.0.0
docutils==0.14
dynamic-reconfigure==1.5.50
edward==1.3.4
entrypoints==0.2.3
enum34==1.1.6
filelock==2.0.11
Flask==0.12.2
future==0.16.0
gast==0.2.0
gazebo-plugins==2.5.17
gazebo-ros==2.5.17
gencpp==0.6.0
geneus==2.2.6
genlisp==0.4.16
genmsg==0.5.11
gennodejs==2.0.1
genpy==0.6.7
glfw==1.5.1
-e git+https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow.git@5f2a6d406184cfd64e4add305f03f2b3090234f4#egg=gpflow
GPy==1.8.5
graphviz==0.8.2
grpcio==1.12.1
gym==0.11.0
h5py==2.7.0
hmmlearn==0.2.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.5
image-geometry==1.12.8
imageio==2.2.0
intel-openmp==2018.0.0
interactive-markers==1.11.4
ipdb==0.10.3
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==6.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==5.1.5
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.10.2
Jinja2==2.9.6
jmespath==0.9.3
joblib==0.10.3
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-client==5.1.0
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
Keras==2.0.6
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
kiwisolver==1.0.1
Lasagne==0.2.dev1
laser-geometry==1.6.4
llvmlite==0.19.0
lxml==4.1.1
Mako==1.0.6
Markdown==2.6.11
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.2.2
message-filters==1.12.14
mistune==0.7.4
mock==2.0.0
mpi4py==2.0.0
msgpack-python==0.4.8
mujoco-py==1.50.1.56
multipledispatch==0.4.9
nbconvert==5.2.1
nbformat==4.3.0
networkx==2.0
nose==1.3.7
nose2==0.6.5
notebook==5.0.0
numba==0.34.0
numexpr==2.6.4
numpy==1.14.4
observations==0.1.4
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.4.1.15
pachi-py==0.0.21
pandas==0.20.3
pandocfilters==1.4.1
paramz==0.8.5
path.py==10.3.1
pbr==3.1.1
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.0.0
pluginlib==1.10.5
progressbar2==3.34.3
prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
protobuf==3.7.1
ptyprocess==0.5.2
pycparser==2.18
pygame==1.9.2a0
pyglet==1.2.4
Pygments==2.2.0
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPrind==2.11.1
pyro-ppl==0.1.2
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-qt-binding==0.3.4
python-utils==2.2.0
pytz==2018.3
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.2
qt-dotgraph==0.3.11
qt-gui==0.3.11
qt-gui-cpp==0.3.11
qt-gui-py-common==0.3.11
qtconsole==4.3.1
requests==2.18.3
resource-retriever==1.12.4
-e git+https://github.com/openai/roboschool.git@a7e7fd5cc8f81e9691f9bbe8c9aab8e87c79bb7d#egg=roboschool
rosbag==1.12.14
rosboost-cfg==1.14.4
rosclean==1.14.4
roscreate==1.14.4
rosgraph==1.12.14
roslaunch==1.12.14
roslib==1.13.6
roslint==0.11.0
roslz4==1.12.14
rosmake==1.14.4
rosmaster==1.12.14
rosmsg==1.12.14
rosnode==1.12.14
rosparam==1.12.14
rospy==1.12.14
rosservice==1.12.14
rostest==1.12.14
rostopic==1.12.14
rosunit==1.14.4
roswtf==1.12.14
rqt-action==0.4.9
rqt-bag==0.4.12
rqt-bag-plugins==0.4.12
rqt-console==0.4.8
rqt-dep==0.4.9
rqt-graph==0.4.9
rqt-gui==0.5.0
rqt-gui-py==0.5.0
rqt-image-view==0.4.13
rqt-launch==0.4.8
rqt-logger-level==0.4.8
rqt-moveit==0.5.7
rqt-msg==0.4.8
rqt-nav-view==0.5.7
rqt-plot==0.4.8
rqt-pose-view==0.5.8
rqt-publisher==0.4.8
rqt-py-common==0.5.0
rqt-py-console==0.4.8
rqt-reconfigure==0.4.10
rqt-robot-dashboard==0.5.7
rqt-robot-monitor==0.5.8
rqt-robot-steering==0.5.9
rqt-runtime-monitor==0.5.7
rqt-rviz==0.5.10
rqt-service-caller==0.4.8
rqt-shell==0.4.9
rqt-srv==0.4.8
rqt-tf-tree==0.5.8
rqt-top==0.4.8
rqt-topic==0.4.10
rqt-web==0.4.8
rviz==1.12.16
s3transfer==0.1.10
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.2.1
seaborn==0.8.1
sensor-msgs==1.12.6
simplegeneric==0.8.1
sip==4.19.12
six==1.11.0
smach==2.0.1
smach-ros==2.0.1
smclib==1.8.3
tensorboard==1.8.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3
tf==1.11.9
tf-conversions==1.11.9
tf2-geometry-msgs==0.5.18
tf2-kdl==0.5.18
tf2-py==0.5.18
tf2-ros==0.5.18
topic-tools==1.12.14
torch==0.3.0.post4
torchvision==0.2.0
tornado==4.5.1
tqdm==4.15.0
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==1.2.3
wiimote==1.12.0
xacro==1.11.3
xlrd==1.2.0
zmq==0.0.0
```

After running `conda env export > myenv.yml` and then deleting the conflicting packages, the .yml file is:

```
name: testingtesting
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.5.2=0
  - pip==10.0.1
  - blas=1.0=openblas
  - bleach=1.5.0
  - ca-certificates=2019.1.23=0
  - click=6.6
  - cycler=0.10.0
  - dbus=1.10.20=0
  - decorator=4.1.2
  - entrypoints=0.2.3
  - expat=2.1.0=0
  - flask=0.12.2
  - fontconfig=2.12.1=3
  - freetype=2.5.5=2
  - glib=2.50.2=1
  - gst-plugins-base=1.8.0=0
  - gstreamer=1.8.0=0
  - h5py=2.7.0
  - hdf5=1.8.17=2
  - html5lib=0.9999999
  - icu=54.1=0
  - ipykernel=4.6.1
  - ipython=6.1.0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0
  - itsdangerous=0.24
  - jbig=2.1=0
  - jedi=0.10.2
  - jinja2=2.9.6
  - jpeg=9b=0
  - jsonschema=2.6.0
  - jupyter_client=5.1.0
  - jupyter_core=4.3.0
  - libffi=3.2.1=1
  - libgcc=5.2.0=0
  - libgcc-ng=8.2.0
  - libgfortran=3.0.0=1
  - libiconv=1.14=0
  - libpng=1.6.27=0
  - libsodium=1.0.10=0
  - libstdcxx-ng=8.2.0
  - libtiff=4.0.6=3
  - libtorch=0.1.12
  - libxcb=1.12=1
  - libxml2=2.9.4=0
  - llvmlite=0.19.0
  - mako=1.0.6
  - markupsafe=0.23
  - mistune=0.7.4
  - mkl=2017.0.3=0
  - mpi4py=2.0.0
  - mpich2=1.4.1p1=0
  - nbconvert=5.2.1
  - nbformat=4.3.0
  - nomkl=1.0=0
  - notebook=5.0.0
  - numba=0.34.0
  - olefile=0.44
  - openblas=0.2.19=0
  - openssl=1.0.2r
  - pandas=0.20.3
  - pandocfilters=1.4.1
  - path.py=10.3.1
  - pcre=8.39=1
  - pexpect=4.2.1
  - pickleshare=0.7.4
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.14
  - ptyprocess=0.5.2
  - pycparser=2.18
  - pygments=2.2.0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0
  - pyqt=5.6.0
  - pyzmq=16.0.2
  - qt=5.6.2=5
  - readline=6.2=2
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1
  - sip=4.19.12
  - sqlite=3.13.0=0
  - swig=3.0.10=0
  - terminado=0.6
  - testpath=0.3.1
  - tk=8.5.18=0
  - tornado=4.5.1
  - traitlets=4.3.2
  - wcwidth=0.1.7
  - xz=5.2.2=1
  - zeromq=4.1.5=0
  - zlib=1.2.8=3
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.2.2
    - astor==0.6.2
    - atari-py==0.1.1
    - azure==1.0.3
    - azure-common==1.1.8
    - azure-mgmt==0.20.2
    - azure-mgmt-common==0.20.0
    - azure-mgmt-compute==0.20.1
    - azure-mgmt-network==0.20.1
    - azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-resource==0.20.1
    - azure-mgmt-storage==0.20.0
    - azure-nspkg==2.0.0
    - azure-servicebus==0.20.1
    - azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.2
    - azure-storage==0.20.3
    - backports-weakref==1.0rc1
    - boto3==1.4.6
    - botocore==1.6.0
    - box2d==2.3.2
    - box2d-kengz==2.3.3
    - box2d-py==2.3.1
    - cached-property==1.3.0
    - cffi==1.11.4
    - chardet==3.0.4
    - cloudpickle==0.4.0
    - colorama==0.3.9
    - cython==0.27.3
    - dill==0.2.7.1
    - docutils==0.14
    - edward==1.3.4
    - enum34==1.1.6
    - filelock==2.0.11
    - future==0.16.0
    - gast==0.2.0
    - glfw==1.5.1
    - gpy==1.8.5
    - grpcio==1.12.1
    - gym==0.11.0
    - hmmlearn==0.2.1
    - idna==2.5
    - imageio==2.2.0
    - intel-openmp==2018.0.0
    - ipdb==0.10.3
    - jmespath==0.9.3
    - jupyter-console==5.2.0
    - keras==2.0.6
    - keras-applications==1.0.7
    - keras-preprocessing==1.0.9
    - kiwisolver==1.0.1
    - lxml==4.1.1
    - markdown==2.6.11
    - matplotlib==2.2.2
    - mock==2.0.0
    - msgpack-python==0.4.8
    - mujoco-py==1.50.1.56
    - multipledispatch==0.4.9
    - networkx==2.0
    - nose==1.3.7
    - nose2==0.6.5
    - numexpr==2.6.4
    - numpy==1.14.4
    - observations==0.1.4
    - opencv-python==3.4.1.15
    - pachi-py==0.0.21
    - paramz==0.8.5
    - path-py==10.3.1
    - pbr==3.1.1
    - pillow==5.0.0
    - progressbar2==3.34.3
    - protobuf==3.7.1
    - pyglet==1.2.4
    - pyopengl==3.1.0
    - pyprind==2.11.1
    - pyro-ppl==0.1.2
    - python-dateutil==2.7.2
    - python-utils==2.2.0
    - pytz==2018.3
    - pyyaml==3.12
    - qtconsole==4.3.1
    - requests==2.18.3
    - s3transfer==0.1.10
    - scikit-learn==0.19.1
    - scipy==1.2.1
    - seaborn==0.8.1
    - setuptools==39.2.0
    - six==1.11.0
    - tensorboard==1.8.0
    - tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - tqdm==4.15.0
    - urllib3==1.22
    - werkzeug==0.14.1
    - wheel==0.31.1
    - xlrd==1.2.0
    - zmq==0.0.0
# prefix: /home/robin/anaconda3/envs/py35lab
```

Then, I managed to create the new environment from the .yml file with `conda env create -f myenv.yml`.

Comment: Can you show the YAML env file? Can't find trace of any `anaconda-tests` package either on anaconda.org or Pypi. Could it be some custom package?
Likely deleting this dependency would solve your issue.